# Rails update_column from within seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, seeding

I have a seed file that generates numerous objects, including *accounts* and *account transactions*. After the accounts are created, a loop generates 80 transactions for each account (there are 150 accounts).

Everything works well, except I need the account's *balance* column to be updated to reflect the change caused by the transaction. I've tried this in 100 different ways. Here is my most recent approach:

from **seeds.rb**

```
accounts.each do |account|
    80.times do
        type = types.sample
            case (type)
                when 1
                    description = descriptions_ATM_Withdrawal.sample
                    amount = (atm_amounts.sample) *-1
                when 2
                    description = descriptions_Check.sample
                    amount = ((500.0 - 5.0) * rand() + 5) *-1
                when 3
                    description = descriptions_Deposit.sample
                    amount = (2000.0 - 5.0) * rand() + 5
                when 4
                    description = descriptions_AutoDraft.sample
                    amount = ((350.0 - 5.0) * rand() + 5) *-1
                when 5
                    description = descriptions_POS.sample
                    amount = ((150.0 - 5.0) * rand() + 5) *-1
                when 6
                    description = descriptions_Transfer
                    amount = (500.0 - 5.0) * rand() + 5
                when 7
                    description = descriptions_Withdrawal
                    amount = ((500.0 - 5.0) * rand() + 5) *-1
                when 99
                    description = descriptions_Miscellaneous
                    amount = ((500.0 - 5.0) * rand() + 5) *-1
            end
        AcctTransaction.create do |transaction|
            transaction.id = SecureRandom.random_number(99999999999999)
            transaction.account_id = account.id
            transaction.transaction_type_id = type
            transaction.description = description
            transaction.amount = amount
            transaction.adjusted_bal = account.balance + transaction.amount
            # keep transaction in chronological order unless it's the first one
            unless AcctTransaction.exists?(account_id: transaction.account_id)
                transaction.date = rand(account.date_opened..Time.now)
            else
                transaction.date = rand(AcctTransaction.where(account_id: transaction.account_id).last.date..Time.now)
            end
        end
        Account.find(AcctTransaction.last.account_id).update_column(:balance, AcctTransaction.last.adjusted_bal)
    end
end
```

Trying to update with the last line before the "ends". I've tried *update, update_attribute*, as well as just "=". Nothing seems to work. The account's "balance" field **MUST** be updated after each transaction in order to provide an accurate basis for calculation in the *next* iteration of the account transaction creation loop.

**Any suggestions will be considered**. This can't be that difficult. Again, the whole thing would work just fine if the balance gets updated like it should.

Rails 4.1.8 / Ruby 2.1.5

Please help.. THANK YOU!

**EDIT
account.rb:**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :acct_type
    has_many :acct_transactions, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :acct_type
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :acct_transactions

    validates :acct_type_id, presence: true

end
```

**acct_transaction.rb**

```
class AcctTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :account
    has_one :transaction_type

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :transaction_type, :allow_destroy => false

end
```

**screen shot of (wrong) results**

[image: transactions view]

As you can see, what happens is the original balance (seen in header if you zoom in), *persists*. Every transaction, therefore, is calculated based on this amount.

**methods in acct_transactions_controller that actually work to perform these updates when the app is live**. Trying to replicate this functionality when creating the nested seeds:

```
  public
    def modify_acct_balance
      account = Account.find(@acct_transaction.account_id)
      case @acct_transaction.transaction_type_id
          when 1,2,4,5,7
              account.update(balance: account.balance - @acct_transaction.amount)
          when 3
            account.update(balance: account.balance + @acct_transaction.amount)
      end
    end

    def adjust_balance
      case @acct_transaction.transaction_type_id
          when 2,4,5,7
            @acct_transaction.adjusted_bal = Account.find(@acct_transaction.account_id).balance - @acct_transaction.amount
          when 3
            @acct_transaction.adjusted_bal = Account.find(@acct_transaction.account_id).balance + @acct_transaction.amount
      end
    end
```

Please note that the above methods calculate differently based on the transaction type (+ or -) - user always supplies positive value. Works though.

**How to reproduce this kind of functionality in the above seed file?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, I had to do 2 things:

1. Change the syntax of update method (last line of seeds.rb) to this : `account.update(balance: transaction.adjusted_bal)`
2. Add a ! (bang) to the create method (`AcctTransaction.create! do |transaction|`)

The create method probably works fine without the bang, but I'm leaving it in because everything works great now. Also, I'm not sure why using **update** only works with this syntax. I tried other variants and other methods to update this column and none seemed to work. Almost seems like seeds.rb only works with "bare bones" Rails methods. Thanks to the Deeno and all others who've helped me work this out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, for sure, but at first glance it looks like your approach would work. My first thought is that the you have some life-cycle hooks or counter-cache configuration on the models that's conflicting with your logic. (You may want to show us your model definitions)

If that's not the case, I'd simply skip updating the balance after every transaction and calculate the balance at the end of the transaction-creation loop.

In pseudo:

```
accounts.each do |account|
  80.times do
    # create transactions
  end

  account.reload
  account.balance = account.transactions.sum(:adjusted_bal)
  account.save
end
```

Or even faster, build and cache the balance locally during transaction-creation:

```
accounts.each do |account|
  balance = 0
  80.times do
    # create transaction
    balance += transaction.amount
  end
  account.balance = balance
  account.save
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but the loop creating the transactions needs to be supplied with the "most current" balance per the changes it made in its last iteration. I'm interested in seeing what could be blocking this. Adding _account.rb_ and _acct_transaction.rb_ to the above post. Also, I'm posting a screen clipping of what I'm trying to achieve in the resultant view for these transactions - to clarify. Also, I forgot to say that the _acct_transactions_controller_ has methods that update the balance fields in both models perfectly (triggered via user actions). Cannot access these in seeds, though.